# Checkboxes not being registered as unchecked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onclick

I found this code on a tutorial online, so apologies if it's a bit weird but it's the only code I've found that works.

I have a `ListView`, where each row has a `CheckBox` and a `TextView`. When a button on the page is clicked, the names of the rows with checked checkboxes are displayed in a separate `TextView` above the `ListView`.

This all works fine, as long as at least one row is checked; if I check 4 checkboxes and press the button, all 4 names are displayed, and then uncheck 2, only the remaining 2 names are displayed.

However, my problem is that when no checkboxes are ticked, the `TextView` displays the name of the last `CheckBox` to be unchecked (assuming at least one has been checked since I started the app).

Why is this, and how can I make nothing be displayed when no checkboxes are checked?

Here is the adapter and a method that's called in onCreate:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

        private ArrayList<Country> countryList;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
            this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView item;
            CheckBox favourite;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.item = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoBox));
                holder.favourite = ((CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder.favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();
                        country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Country country = countryList.get(position);
            holder.item.setText(country.getName());
            holder.favourite.setChecked(country.isSelected());
            holder.favourite.setTag(country);

            return convertView;

        }

    }

    private void checkButtonClick() {


  Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
  myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       String stringName = "";

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;
    for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++){
      Country country = countryList.get(i);
     if(country.isSelected()){
     stringName = (stringName + country.getName());

     TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
     t.setText(stringName);

     }

   }
   }
  });
```

No errors appear in compilation or runtime so unfortunately I can't post a logCat!

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you try moving `TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)); t.setText(stringName);` outside (after) for-loop?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly but doing that has solved my problem, thank you so much! If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    String stringName = "";

    ArrayList<Country> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;

    for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++){
        Country country = countryList.get(i);
        if(country.isSelected()){
            stringName = (stringName + country.getName());

            // ---------The problem is here: 
            // This code is unreachable when none of the checkboxes is checked               

            TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1));
            t.setText(stringName);
        }
    }
}
```

Consider the case when none of the `checkboxes` is checked. By logic, `if (country.isSelected())` will return `false`. So, the code inside the `if-block` will not be executed even once. And the TextView's value will remain same as it was before.

Solution: Move the finding of and setting text to TextView until after the for-loop is through.

Now, in case none of `if` statements evaluate to `true`(i.e. none of the `checkboxes` are checked), variable `stringName` will hold the value of `"" (empty String)`, which is exactly what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems with CheckBoxes in a ListView you can take a Boolean array initialized false in the beginning and then making true the corresponding position in the array where checkbox is checked in the ListView. This will not cause a trouble in checked state of checkboxes when you move forward and backward in your application.

Comment: I guess that probably could work, however I'm not very good with android and I doubt I'd get it right. Also, I have another feature which I can only get to work using holders, so this current method would use much less extra code than a boolean array as getView etc is already being called.

Comment: I have used it and it mostly eliminates all the drawbacks of ListView with CheckBoxes. Accept my answer if it works for you.

Comment: I would try it but it turns out that the commenter's answer actually works!

Answer (score 0):

Here checkboxstate is the boolean array:

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                        checkBoxState[pos] = true;
                    else
                        checkBoxState[pos] = false;

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but as I said the commenter's answer worked.